# Store Looped MySQL Array as String Variable

Tags: php, mysql, string, variables, loops

I have a collection of results from a MySQL query being fetched in a loop.
I need to store them as a single variable with a space in between each result.

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT Names FROM table");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    echo $row['Names'] . " ";
}
```

So later, I can call 'echo $Names;' and get the string of names with a space in between.

ex) Clinton Bush Huckabee Romney etc....

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$Names = '';
$result = mysql_query("SELECT Names FROM table");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    $Names.= $row['Names'] . " ";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT Names FROM table");

$names = "";

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    $names .= $row['Names'] . " ";
}

echo $names;
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, please, stop using mysql extention. It's [deprecated](http://news.php.net/php.internals/53799). Try [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php).

```
$names = array();
$result = mysql_query("SELECT Names FROM table");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    $names[] = $row['Names'];
}
echo implode(' ', $names);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use an array and then implode it using a space:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT Names FROM table");
$arr = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) $arr[] = $row['Names'];
echo implode(' ', $arr);
```